# How can I define the variable for the awk filter?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I know I can use "`//`" in `awk` to filter the special line, for example:

```
echo -e "aaa bbb ccc\nddd eee fff" | awk '/bbb/ {print $3}'
```

The output is:

```
ccc
```

I want to define a variable for values in "`//`", like `Bash shell`:

```
#!/bin/bash
re="bbb"
echo -e "aaa bbb ccc\nddd eee fff" | awk '/${re}/ {print $3}'
```

But it can't work. How can I define the variable for the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `~` operator with an `awk` variable:

```
awk -v re="$re" '$0 ~ re { print $3 }'
```

Comment: and it works even with environment: awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["re"] { print $3 }'

Comment: @user1708042 That will only work if you export the variable: `export re=bbb`

Comment: There's normally no reason to do that.

Comment: I agree on the export, I'm not sure about on the "normally": still I just wanted to add a bit. In some circumstances it is useful.I used it to pass the same value to multiple invocations of the same awk script from differene shell scripts. It was shorter to write.

Comment: Normally you only export variables that are designed to control the behavior of other applications. You don't export variables that are just for use within the script.